# Not repeating types used as template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Given the code below is there a nicer way to right it that doesn't repeat `typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` twice?

```
template<class T, class T2>
struct foo :
    bar<
        foo<T, T2>, typename 
        std::conditional<
            std::is_same<typename 
                std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category,  //Repeated
                std::random_access_iterator_tag
            >::value,
            std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename 
            std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category       //Repeated
        >::type
    >
{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it up (like it should be anyway):

```
// put in detail namespace/file or something in real code
template<class T, class T2>
struct foo_base
{
    typedef foo<T, T2> foo_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category category_type;

    static const bool random_access = std::is_same<category_type,
                                        std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value;
    typedef typename std::conditional<random_access,
                                        std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                                        category_type>::type tag_type;

    typedef bar<foo_type, tag_type>::type base_type;
}

template<class T, class T2>
struct foo :
   foo_base<T, T2>::base_type
{};
```

Even if there was no repeated bit, you should still split it up to keep the base type logic separate from actually inheriting the base type.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems so obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

You could `typedef` it:

```
typedef std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category it_cat;
```

Comment: Is this compileable? Where do you propose to put this code? Note that `T` is a template parameter.

Comment: @Vlad, can we say:

typedef std::iterator_traits<typename T>::iterator_category it_cat;

Comment: @Sheen: That doesn't make sense. You still need a place to put the `typedef` between the `foo` and base class list.

Comment: @Sheen: the same problem: where are you going to put this code? Under a separate `template<...>` it won't work, because C++ accepts only template classes/structs and functions/methods, but (pretty inconsistently) not typedefs.